# Migrating from Confluence Questions to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, stack-overflow-enterprise

We are using Confluence Questions by Atlassian for a while.  We are evaluating Stack Overflow for Teams as a possible alternative.  Is there a way we can export the questions and answers from Confluence into Stack Overflow?

Comment: Note that Confluence has a completely different markup syntax (or rather, Stack Overflow's markup isn't a superset of Confluence's). The easiest way to convert it would probably be to HTML, which makes question and answer sources look ugly. I wonder whether the Stack Overflow magicians will be able to work around that? (Probably.)

Comment: Exporting is on Confluence's end - you should check with them what formats are possible. And then match the format against whatever import options Stack Overflow has and ask about what can be massaged or supported.